# How to update interface (html pages) in electron desktop application?

Tags: node.js, cross-platform, electron

Well, there is application which is written on node.js + electron. There is a website located on remote server. There is need in keeping the design of the website and functions that are added/changed to it in this desktop app. What is the easiest way to do this?

Note: The application has Bluetooth, USB connection, that is reachable from this web interface in app.